# See who is upvoting/ downvoting my question/answer

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, up-votes

Is there any way for me to see who is upvoting or downvoting me? Apart from looking at the data dump, of course.

No, I will *not* go after those who downvoted me, but it's interesting to know, anyway.

Comment: Lately I've often been thinking that it would be nice if I could see that I was downvoted in the first place.

Comment: @Manni - This is shown as part of you voting data in the envelope view. It will show all up and down votes. Unless your looking for something else?

Comment: I feel bad enough downvoting as it is, and while I always try to leave a comment, sometimes I just can't bring myself to do it :(

Comment: Explaining a downvote is not without risk.  Sometimes you get a string of downvotes on old answers in return.

Comment: @Diago: I am talking about the envelope-thingy, yes. But I have my doubts about its correctness. I'll keep an eye on that thing an report a bug when my suspicions are confirmed.

Comment: @Andomar: That is true, unfortunately. But it shouldn't keep you from explaining your downvotes. I suggest to report revenge downvotes immediately.

Comment: What?! -2 points? Now I have another reason to know *who* downovoted me, and why :)

Comment: +1 I wouldn't mind my own downvotes being visible.  If I don't leave a comment its because I'm lazy, not because I'm afraid of revenge voting.

Comment: +1, there really should be a rule about leaving a comment when you down vote. i just had a down vote and run for one of my questions and it is completely non-constructive. i don't particularly care who did it but what is the point of a down vote if there is no explanation as to why i got it? i can't change whatever the person had a problem with without an explanation so to me that is just someone being a d*#@ for no reason.

Comment: I actually don't care who voted down, but why. So it would be nice if a down vote would only be possible after leaving a comment. SO asks to add a comment, but it does not require it. That's bad.

Comment: I'm working on a Java application that tracks this. I will release the source on GitHub shortly. There are too many comment-less / serial downvotes for this to be a good system otherwise. It's simple to track by measuring the -1 cost of a downvote and the timing of the downvote.

Comment: @Hack-R, how can you do that when the data that you can access is already anonymous?

Comment: @Andomar Never fear, the StackExchange serial downvoting system is here! They'll take care of your serial downvotes, so no worries!

Answer (score 174, accepted):

**No**

Voting is anonymous and not even the moderators have access to this information. The only people I suspect that can see is the Stack Exchange development team.

*From the comments: Voting data is made anonymous before the data dump is done so this information is not available in the data dump.*

**Clarification**

There are scripts that run that check for voting anomalies that will indicate when a user has a high rate of up-votes or down-votes from a particular user, however these instances are rare and handled by the team.

Comment: I don't think this information is available in the data dump, as this would defeat the anonymity.

Comment: correct - voting data is anonymized pre-dump

Comment: what exactly does high rate mean? and how often does this script check run?

Comment: @AdityaGameProgrammer: The details of the anti-serial-voting script are not really publicized (lest people try and game the algorithm), but e.g. two accounts upvoting each other all day long will be probably caught by this.

Comment: @Piskvor fair enough.But if a person really wanted to game it observation and analysis would be enough to figure it out for most part.

Comment: However, not forcing someone to leave a comment when downvoting will not be helpful to the guy whose answer was downvoted. He will be clueless as to why a perfectly valid answer (according to him) was downvoted..

Comment: I have a downvote stalker.. I doubt that the aforementioned  scripts are working.
Either that, or I suddenly became very good when I created a new account

Answer (score 44):

Confirmed that the Upvoter / Downvoter `UserId`'s are zapped from the `Votes` table, e.g. by running this [data.stackexchange](http://data.stackexchange.com) query. Note however that 'favourited' and bounty Userid's seem to be retained :) (Thanks, mom!)

```
SELECT v.UserId, vt.Name, COUNT(*)
   FROM 
     Posts p
       INNER JOIN Votes v
         ON v.PostId = p.Id
       INNER JOIN VoteTypes vt
         ON v.VoteTypeId = vt.Id
  WHERE
     p.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
  GROUP BY 
    vt.Name, v.UserId
  ORDER BY 1,3
```

Comment: If someone has the balls to downvote against someone who made the effort, they deserve to get a reason or condition to improve. Often the critic is ill informed or ill-willed if silent

Comment: All self-styled Einstiens have this problem of downvoting questions and answers in a rush, to prove their superioty and that too without an explanation.  Recently I have been a victim of the same. I do not know WHY downvoted.

Comment: Having around 13 upvotes on an answer, I am still thinking what went terribly wrong for that person who downvoted without even having the courtesy to explain.

Comment: SO should develop this functionality, those who are downvoting, before that they should post a reason to downvote.

Comment: Does this query work on data.stackexchange? I cannot run the query because it doesn't recognize my username Axion004 for the column name.

Comment: @Axion004 your `UserId` is 689395 (a numeric value at the top of your profile page).