# Finding out who voted on my question or answer

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See Who is Upvoting/ Downvoting My Question/Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer)

Can I see which user(s) have upvoted or downvoted my questions and/or answers?

Comment: Of course there isn't a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer

Comment: Duplicates? On Meta? Never.....

Comment: -1 this is too easy a topic to search and somehow create dupes for...

Comment: The automatic dupe search (when you're entering the question title) does not work as well on meta as on the "proper" sites (SO/SF/SU.)  Yes it's a dupe but here's a sympathy upvote.

Answer (score 4):

No

All votes are anonymous. Kind of like elections. That makes sure no one is pressured to vote a certain way.

This acts in both a good and bad way. People can downvote posts that they think are bad. But, if someone thinks it is a good post, while a lot of other people think it is bad, they can upvote knowing that there is full anonymity.

The only thing you can see is the balance (`Upvotes - Downvotes = Balance`), or when you get to 1,000 reputation, the breakdown of those. (`Upvotes` vs `Downvotes`)