# is it possible to find out who downvotes a question/answer?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

is it possible to find out who downvotes a question/answer?

Comment: Why? If you've suffered a serial downvote (lots of downvotes from the same user in a short period of time) this will be caught, the votes removed and your rep recalculated.

Comment: i find there are downvotes without an explanation and that's the reason for my question.

Comment: see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes

Comment: I think that's a 42904:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not. The rationale behind it is that this would prompt vendettas/mutual-downvoting-wars etc...

Why do you wish to know?

If it's to ask "Why did you down-vote", your best bet is to add a comment to that effect.

If you believe the down-vote was malicious (especially in a pattern), wait 2-3 days for the system to fix it (So has jobs which nullify serial down-votes) and if not, ask SO team (the email is available on the Contact link IIRC) to look into this. You can also try to attract moderator's attention (either on SO, or by posting details on Meta)

If you just want to revenge the down-vote with one of your own, i somewhat sympathize on a personal level BUT, leaving aside large scale issue like "good of the SO ecosystem", do you think you'd like it if YOUR down-votes would be retaliated against?

Comment: @DVK my motive is not revenge or anything else like it
As a basic courtesy I would expect someone to explain why they downvoted.
I donot know how you thought I am on a revenge spree :)

Since you have told SO has systems to check patterns of downvote my question is if someone downvotes different questions without even reading the answers will the system check it?

I know there are few questions already on this topic. Hope you understand.

Comment: If you mean the same person downvotes multiple posts of yours, yes, this is supposed to be caught and reversed automatically. Also, I didn't think you were on a revenge spree, thus that option was last in the list of 3 :=)

Answer (score 1):

No, voting is anonymous.