# Can ♦ moderators see who voted for something?

Tags: discussion, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [See Who is Upvoting/ Downvoting My Question/Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer)

Can ♦ moderators see who has voted for a post/comment?

#### Edit:

If this isn't possible, how can moderators modify users' votes? (I've seen this happen.)

Comment: This was mentioned here somewhere...

Comment: That other post has no real answer to this question.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: right at the top, in Diego's answer: `Voting is anonymous and not even the moderators have access to this information. `

Comment: @Jeff, @Anna: The reason I asked is that I have personally *seen* a moderator remove a downvote. While not questioning what they did (it was the right action in the situation), how is that possible, if they can't see who has voted for what?

Comment: @Mehrdad They can't do that (unless the downvote they removed was their own, of course). The site will automatically remove votes if it detects someone mass-voting on another person; maybe it was that

Comment: @Michael: No -- the moderator *specifically removed **my** downvote*, because the downvotee's temper was getting out of hand. The mod even *mentioned* that this was done; I'm not taking guesses -- and I appreciate that fact, since it was the right thing to do. But the question is, how was that done? (No, the mod wasn't Jeff, or -- AFAIK -- any member on the dev team.)

Comment: @Mehrdad most likely they "upvoted to offset the downvote" ... once you get to so many reputation (it varies by site, check the privileges list for the site in question) then you can see the up/down vote ratio by clicking on a particular score (# between the arrows). But as @Michael noted, only the automated scanner will invalidate (remove) votes. ~~ Caveat: A dev _could_ remove it, by hand, but the reasons would have to be magnanimous and paramount. Can you recall _where_ the downvote was removed? (which Question, and by Whom)

Comment: @jcolebrand: Oh, that's what happened? OK, but how come my downvote button was no longer orange after that happened?

Comment: @Mehrdad ~ You downvoted and then your downvote tick was taken away? Did you only downvote the user once or did you downvote the same user many times?

Comment: @jcolebrand: ***No, I didn't***. I know what I did. Like I said, even the **moderator** mentioned in a comment that this was done (they specifically used the word "revoke"). I would mention the post/moderator but I'd rather not put them on the spot, as since I mentioned, the action was appropriate.

Comment: Then you're doing all of us a disservice. You make an accusation that an action was taken and then go "but I refuse to tell anyone what thing was done, so :p" and then we have to shrug and say "you're wrong, but you'll never believe us that you're wrong". And don't get so forcefully upset "No I didn't" when I ask for _clarification_ of what you did in the first place. I'm still hazy on the details. I don't know what actions were taken. You commented that the orange downvote was missing, but I don't quite understand what that means.

Comment: @jcolebrand: In that case, [here is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814869/playing-an-arbitrary-sound-on-windows) (Edit: Had the wrong link at first; fixed). (Let it be known that I didn't mean to put it here to make the mod look bad -- just wanted to know how this was possible.)

Comment: @Mehrdad ~ MarcG is a dev. He can revoke things that we diamonds cannot.

Comment: @Meh, this is a special case (and I'm not sure we are interpreting Marc's answer correctly) but he's a developer, who has direct access to the database. He's not just "a mod". The answer to your question is in the duplicate, the answer to what transpired in the comments, is that.

Comment: @jcolebrand, @Juan: Ooh wow, stupid me. I had no idea devs are also diamond moderators (aside from Jeff). Thanks for the info.