# How do I identify who votes on my question?

Tags: discussion, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See Who is Upvoting/ Downvoting My Question/Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer)

I am a new user of this site. Many users give up and down votes to questions. So how do I identify who votes on my question?

Comment: i check all question then i generate this question? if it is duplicate then i will delete it .

Comment: Don't worry - I couldn't find the duplicate either despite knowing that it existed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

Voting is anonymous by design.