# What is the right way to get some clarification for downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See Who is Upvoting/ Downvoting My Question/Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer)

I posted a solution to a question at: [Forward olddomain.com/$ to newdomain.com/$](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6839712/303363)

However, I got 2 downvotes and I see -4 in my 'Users' tab for this.

`-4     11 mins ago     downvote    Forward olddomain.com/$ to newdomain.com/$`

Now, I don't know who downvoted this and why. Is there anyway to know who the downvoters are and ask them to clarify?

Comment: Bah.  Couldn't find that one.  Thanx @Cody.

Comment: The question is off topic.  You should have flagged as such and moved on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've already done is about all you can do:  post a comment asking for justification.  There is no way to directly contact anyone even if you did know who it was that downvoted, but of course downvoting is anonymous.

Comment: Please don't do that, though. Posting comments about downvotes is just noise, and it's unlikely that anyone will respond. Downvotes are meant to be anonymous; that's the real lesson here. It is impossible to know who the downvoters are or to ask them to explain their actions.

Answer (score 2):

Down-votes are anonymous, and there's no particular way to establish who did them.

But, they are done for good reason, as people don't simply down-vote out of petty reasons.

If they do actually down-vote you for petty reasons, there are many more people who will up-vote your post if it is good enough anyway.