# Finding a person?

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See Who is Upvoting/ Downvoting My Question/Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer)

Is there any way to find out the person who is upvoting a question or answer on Stack Overflow?

Comment: No - all voting is anonymous.

Comment: The question is, why would you need to, really?

Comment: @tombull89 : Just to know in general. Thats all.

Comment: @SPK: Don't think of it in terms of you wanting to see who voted on you; Think of it in terms of whether you want people to see how you voted on them. Imagine a world where people weren't always professional and responsible and sometimes held grudges against otherwise anonymous people who are just trying to participate in the community. Voting is anonymous simply as another mechanism to try to protect the community from trolls and to promote repercussion-less participation in the community, by the community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, voting is anonymous. It is intended that way.