# Why can't I see who downvoted?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See Who is Upvoting/ Downvoting My Question/Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer)

I have low rep on a stack and have had some questions down-voted. I would love to see by whom but I don't have enough rep and I got to thinking, why isn't that feature available to everyone? It would make voters much more accountable (especially voters with low rep who don't know that feature even exists).

Comment: That feature's not available to anyone, allegedly even developers can't see who voted on their own posts (though they can view other user's votes for developer-y reasons)

Comment: @BenBrocka We can if we really want to (we have DB access, so in the end all the information is there). But there's a debugging UI that easily shows you all votes on a post with three clicks, and *that UI* is disabled for own posts. So it's possible, but it requires jumping through more hoops.

Answer (score 15):

> I would love to see by whom but I don't have enough rep and I got to thinking, why isn't that feature available to everyone?

Voting is anonymous, no one can see who up / down voted their posts, regardless of reputation.

> It would make voters much more accountable (especially voters with low rep who don't know that feature even exists).

No, not really. What such a feature would do, however, would be to encourage revenge down voting. We don't want that.

Comment: You again? I *definitely* smell moderator material.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks! One diamond is enough for me, though, I'm already a moderator on Programmers.

Answer (score 12):

> It would make voters much more accountable

No it wouldn't. Being able to harass someone isn't the same as being able to call them to account. If someone wants you to know why they voted, they can tell you that already; there's nothing you can do - even if you know the person involved - to *force* them to do so.

There are three pieces of information that are relevant to this discussion:

1. Who voted
2. How they voted
3. Why they voted

You know #2 right now. #1 and #3 are not known to anyone but the voter himself. Of the two, only #3 is likely to be useful to you, and only if it pertains to something you could change on your post.

If someone has constructive suggestions for improvement, they can post those as comments. They can do this *even if they can't or don't care to vote*. If no one has done so, then there's no possible way for the system to expose that information anyway. So you're left with the choice of either looking for problems with your question yourself, or ignoring the votes and moving on.

You might also be interested in the information linked to from [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: can you please let me know how you made this answer a community wiki answer?

Comment: @JeremyThompson: There's a `community wiki` checkbox underneath the text area for answering questions.