# Can I know who are voters of my question or answer?

Tags: discussion, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See Who is Upvoting/ Downvoting My Question/Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer)

Vote feature is very nice in all related Stack OverFlow sites. But sometimes I would like to know who are my voters of my question and answer. Is there any way to know voters or can I know who are voters of my question or answer?

Comment: When a voter (either up or down) want to expose himself he does so by leaving a comment. Otherwise - it means he prefer to keep himself hidden and that's totally fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you can't. Voting is *deliberately* kept anonymous.

Even moderators do not know who voted on what.

Comment: To clarify: The system and the developers do (of course), which allows checks for voting frauds.