# Tools for tracing voting patterns

Tags: support, voting, moderator-tools

On our site (Econ.SE) we recently experienced an unusual spike in down-voting behaviour (a single day with 50 downvotes, whereas the usual level of downvoting on the site is around 5 per day).

Do the moderators have any special tools to trace what was going on and figure out if there is anything suspicious about this spike? The only tool I'm aware of is the "Suspicious Votes" page, which is currently blank.

Comment: Did upvotes increase also? 5 votes per day is pretty low (I vote more than that myself, sometimes even on sites that I'm not consistently active), so you could simply have a few new users.

Comment: @Cai the number of upvotes appears to have been broadly normal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this answer from an experienced moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211117/245360):

> Moderators can see votes in the *aggregate cast between specific users*. If the percentage of such votes seems to be too high, it can be an indicator of serial voting. But we also use other criteria to make that determination.

So if the voting wasn't targeted at a specific user but rather to the entire site, that information doesn't show up in the page you have.

I think the only option you have is to contact one of the Community Managers to let them dig into the system.

Also, from the public visible *Active users* page, there seem to be [just a few voters on the site](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=week). If you analyze that information, together with the list of [users who obtained a voting badge (Suffrage)](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/62/suffrage), you can see that the only user who is in both lists is you... Since you only voted 14 times this month, you can't be responsible for the number of votes alone. As far as I am concerned, nothing suspicious.